# Looking for guidance on embedded .NET database (such as db4o, NHibernate, or RavenDB)

Tags: nhibernate, db4o, embedded-database, ravendb

I have an object model that I want to store using an embedded database. I have so far been looking at db4o, NHibernate to SQLCE (w/ linq), and RavenDB. This would be used in a desktop C# application.

The key features I am looking to leverage are: Linq or similar for queries (no SQL or HQL), Embedded data engine, pocos, poco first model, no install (no registry or similar)

Can any one suggest one? Are the three I am looking at the best choices? Are there other options? Of the three, can anyone recommend one over the other?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedded database for .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684595/embedded-database-for-net)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842189/good-embedded-database-solution-like-sqlite-for-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271319/lightweight-sql-database-which-doesnt-require-installation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well the three suggested databases are very different in their nature. SQLCE with Hibernate as RDBMS with a ORM, db4o as object database and RavenDB as document database. Each of them has its strengths.

**SQL CE & NHibernate-Combo**
The good:

- Extremely good support in tooling, the knowledge and a big community is there
- Easy to upgrage to MS SQL servers
- Extrem good reporting support
- The power of SQL

The bad:

- Needs mapping
- The mapping between the OO and relational world is not easy and can lead to issues with complex models.

**RavenDB**

The good:

- Doesn't need any mapping
- Easy to use
- Powerful indexing
- JSON & HTTP access

The bad:

- If your domain doesn't fit to a document-oriented approach, it will be quite painful
- It does not support the .NET Framework Client Profile (which is of particular importance as the OP's question is concerning embedded databases)

**db4o**

The good:

- Doesn't need any mapping
- Easy to use
- The storage model is close the object-model. This also works for very complex models.
  -

The bad:

- Tooling support is weak.

Afaik all three support LINQ and POCO-first approach. However since NHibernate & SQL CE still need tons of mapping its not as friction free as it could be.

I think if your focus is on POCO first, LINQ-support, ebedded usage and easy to use, I would try RaveDB or db4o. 
If your focus is on 'safety', community-knowledge, tool-support and reporting I would go with NHibernate and SQL CE.

Comment: Thanks. Given that my domain is not so large as to make the mapping effort too much effort, I believe the NHibernate approach might be best. Primarily because of the community support. RavenDB is a bit too new to have a large knowledge base yet.

Comment: As an *embedded* database, NHibernate has serious issues. I'd choose Linq-To-SQL or EntityFramework4 long before choosing NHibernate at this point. Both of those technologies are baked into the framework and have no external dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

[Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) is a terrific embedded database which has long supported all the modern features of an enterprise database:

- ANSI SQL
- ACID
- Stored procedures
- Triggers

You can get the [.NET provider](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/) (last updated May 24th according to the site) and it supports Entity Framework and Linq.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684595/embedded-database-for-net). For LINQ support, check out  [DbLinq](https://www.ohloh.net/p/dblinq), or since you already intend to use NHibernate you can use NHibernate's own LINQ provider.

Comment: I did see those other posts. The problem was that they focus on embedded relational  data stores, and I am looking for something to store an object model in. They provide options for behind NHibernate. 

DbLinq would provide me a linq provider to the underlying datastore, but it will not provide the rich POCO first model I am looking for.

I do appreciate the suggestion, and if I go with NHibernate, I might consider those options. However, I am still looking for suggestions for what would work best at the POCO first model.

Comment: @David B: see fluent nhibernate's auto mappings: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping

Comment: Thanks, that has been what I was considering. However, I have been seeing more positive news about the other two lately, and was hoping to find out if NHibernate was still the defacto choice.