# Correct solution for persistent table/grid in C# that does not require a full database solution?

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite, datagrid

My WinForms C#/.NET application requires a table/grid control to display records to the end user.  The records will be simple, containing only two fields, a string and a date/time field.  I need to persist the data and I am wondering what the most efficient control and storage back-end is to use.  The data is non-critical (i.e. - not health or financial records, or anything sensitive requiring extensive safety or any encryption).

One solution I have found so far is the DataGrid control in conjunction with SQL Server Compact Edition.  I learned about this solution from this tutorial:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

It seems though that this may be overkill for my application.  In addition, I am worried about the complexities of installing SQL Server CE, especially when it comes to admin vs. user account privilege issues during installation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(v=vs.80).aspx

Is there a table or grid control with built-in file load/save capabilities that uses a simple disk file as the storage method, perhaps a comma delimited ASCII file?  I'd like something that I can still use SQL (via LINQ) to interface with.  also, I am hoping that this can be done transparently.  That is, if I want to upgrade to an SQL database engine solution later, the code from my end that interfaces with the data would not change (except perhaps for the database open/create code of course).

Or am I better off simply biting the bullet and going with SQL Server CE or perhaps SQLite:

[Good embedded database solution (like SQLite) for .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842189/good-embedded-database-solution-like-sqlite-for-net)

If you have any caveats or anecdotes regarding installation issues and ease of use, they would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In my projects, we use Object datasources.  Grid's can be bound to collections of objects just as easily as they can dataTables.  You can store/restore the data using a simple serialization engine (XmlSerializer is rather easy to implement).  Make a basic object, use List or BindingList as the dataset, and serialize/de-serialize it in the backEnd when you need it.

List and BindingList both support Linq queries.

Adding database save later is as simple as writing the code that saves the object to the database, in place of the serialization code, no change to the front end at all.

As far as a "Correct" solution is concerned...there are so many different ways to do it that it boils down to personal preference, and possibly actual requirements and expected future development.  I find it easier to code using objects because the data manipulation is easier, but if you are going for straight record entry, no data manipulation required, going direct to a database is easier.  It just depends on the data and what you plan on doing with it.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know of a concise tutorial that demonstrates the technique you suggest (a Grid control with an Object datasource)?  I found this so far: http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection

Comment: That tutorial shows just about everything you would need to know.  Object, PropertyChanged, BindingList, etc etc.  You can declare a custom list implementation and implement the IBindingList interface yourself, although that is somewhat of a POTA!! (been there, done that, dont want to ever have to do it again).  Look a little into the basic implementation of XmlSerializer and that should be the rest of the basics to get something working.

Comment: A little more complicated than just the basics, but it includes those as well.  This example focuses on the attributes, which let you get fancy as far as exactly what the xml your object generates actually looks like.  Handy when passing it back and forth across networks (SOAP and other similar protocols).   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14064/Using-the-XmlSerializer-Attributes

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend you to use an embedded database, because it will be easier to go to a full database in a near future. SQL Server CE is a good option, and if you want to go big you can simply go to a full SQL Server Database with minimal changes in your code, the only downside of SQL Server CE is that you need to install it and it requires the .NET Framework 4, aside from that I don't see a big problem with it.

Comment: +1 for the embedded db route. Note however that at this time SQL CE is not supported in Windows Store Apps (formerly Metro). Sqlite IS supported. Just something to keep in mind if Windows 8 is a potential target platform.

Comment: @chuex, Thanks, as he don't mention WinRT or Windows Store Apps, I assume he refers to full .NET development, but of course if you're targeting WinRT, the only supported database (as of now) is SQLite, with no option to go for a higher database, unless you want to use Web Services and OData.